# Why .on('load', function) not working on JS templating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

I inject mustachejs templates in my page, then I have a function to fire on these templates.

**JS such:**

```
function loadToggleCSS() {
    console.log("loadToggleCSS : fired!");
    $("button").toggleClass('status0').toggleClass('status1');
    console.log("loadToggleCSS : finished!");
}

$('body').on('load', loadToggleCSS); // <------ this doesn't fire on template

loadToggleCSS(); //  <------------------------- this DOES fire!
```

**Can someone explain WHY the first fails.**

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RXe2t/15/

Comment: Just trigger `loadToggleCSS` at the bottom of the `.getJSON` callback handler instead. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXe2t/16/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<body>` element doesn't (directly) load external content, so it doesn't have a `load` event.

Use `window` instead (wrap the `window` object itself with jQuery, don't try to select a `<window>` element).

```
$(window).on('load', loadToggleCSS);
```

[See an example](http://jsbin.com/ejodij/1/edit)